# Как сделать такие поля формы (поясняющий текст типа placeholder поднимается вверх)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Делаю следующие поля у формы, когда при фокусе поясняющий текст поднимается над полем:

[image: Желаемый результат]

```css
.input_block {
 margin: 0 0 25px 0;
 width: 344px;
 height: 66px;
 position: relative;
}

.input_block input {
 display: block;
 padding: 0;
 width: 344px;
 height: 64px;
 border: none;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
 background: none;
 font-family: "ProximaNovaBold";
 font-size: 24px;
 color: #000;
 outline: none;
}

.input_block label {
 display: block;
 width: 344px;
 height: 64px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

.input_block label span {
 display: block;
 height: 24px;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
 font-family: "ProximaNovaBold";
 font-size: 24px;
 line-height: 24px;
 color: #000;
 position: absolute;
 top: 21px;
 left: 0;
}

.input_block input:focus + label span {
 font-size: 14px;
 top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
    
    <div class="input_block">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name_input">
        <label for="name_input">
            <span>Full Name:</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="input_block">
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone_input">
        <label for="phone_input">
            <span>Phone Number:</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    
</form>
```

Как сделать, чтобы при наличии текста в поле поясняющий текст не возвращался в исходное состояние, а оставался над полем?

Comment: http://codepen.io/andytran/pen/RPBdgM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавлять класс тем полям, у которых есть значение.

```js
$('input').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val())
    $(this).addClass('has_value');
  else
    $(this).removeClass('has_value');
});
```

```css
.input_block {
  margin: 0 0 25px 0;
  width: 344px;
  height: 66px;
  position: relative;
}

.input_block input {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  width: 344px;
  height: 64px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  background: none;
  font-family: "ProximaNovaBold";
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #000;
  outline: none;
}

.input_block label {
  display: block;
  width: 344px;
  height: 64px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.input_block label span {
  display: block;
  height: 24px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  font-family: "ProximaNovaBold";
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 21px;
  left: 0;
}

.input_block input:focus+label span {
  font-size: 14px;
  top: -10px;
}

.has_value+label span {
  font-size: 14px;
  top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="#" method="post">

  <div class="input_block">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name_input">
    <label for="name_input">
            <span>Full Name:</span>
        </label>
  </div>

  <div class="input_block">
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone_input">
    <label for="phone_input">
            <span>Phone Number:</span>
        </label>
  </div>

</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/TheDeadOne/nh13xf7o/1/